# After the successful installation of 'myApp" application. I need to call a service method. May I know is it possible to call the method

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

i have searched on google but not able to know which event/method is called when the application finishes its installation successfully.i am lookin something like
 if(isAppInstalled)  {creating a soap method and sending tags to web service}.
any suggestion?
thanks.

Comment: Don't you know the app has been installed when it's launched? I'm confused.

Comment: Not possible, even if you find a solution, your app is gonna get rejected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. You will have to wait until the user launches your app to be able to execute any code.